# How will i shuffle input form elements in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making an application which will have form with dynamic input elements. With dynamic i mean that those inputs will come from the server side. Here's the psedo sample html :

```
<form>
  <section1>
    <static-field-1></static-field-1>
    <static-field-2></static-field-2>
    <dynamic-field-1></dynamic-field-1>    
    <dynamic-field-2></dynamic-field-2>        
  </section1>

  <section2>//'a' postfix is just for differenting
    <dynamic-field-1a></dynamic-field-1a>    
    <static-field-1a></static-field-1a>
    <static-field-2a></static-field-2a>
    <dynamic-field-2a></dynamic-field-2a>        
  </section2>
</form>
```

In short all the form rendering including their position will be decided by the api response from the server.

The api response will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "section_pos":1,
    "name":"section1",
    "fields":[
      {
        "type":"static",
        "name":"static-field-1"
      },
      {
        "type":"static",
        "name":"static-field-2"
      },
      {
        "type":"dynamic",
        "name":"dynamic-field-1",
        "input":"text",
        "validation":"required"
      },
      {
        "type":"dynamic",
        "name":"dynamic-field-2",
        "input":"number",
        "validation":"required"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section_pos":2,
    "name":"section2",
    "fields":[

      {
        "type":"dynamic",
        "name":"dynamic-field-1a",
        "input":"text",
        "validation":"required"
      },
      {
        "type":"static",
        "name":"static-field-1a"
      },
      {
        "type":"static",
        "name":"static-field-2a"
      },
      {
        "type":"dynamic",
        "name":"dynamic-field-2a",
        "input":"number",
        "validation":"required"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How will i create the dynamic input form elements and shuffle them in their respective section in accordance with the data sent from the server.

With the static i mean , these will be already present/known to us. Dynamic fields are the once that are sent by the server. Server also will sent the order in which each fields(static/dynamic) should be aligned. 
Need help in this task

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question right.
If you want to list all fields as INPUT tag in server's response order:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of mySuperProvider.getDataFromServer()">
  <h2>{{section.name}}</h2>
  <p *ngFor="let field of section.fields">
    <b>{{field.name}}</b>
    <input type="text" ... >
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want to shuffle fields, you can do it in provider or:

```
<p *ngFor="let field of shuffle(section.fields)">
```

Where shuffle() is a function:

```
  shuffle(array) {
    return array.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
  }
```

If you want to show only specific types, and exclude others, then you can use *ngIf.

If you need instead of INPUT tag use Configurable Reactive Forms, then see nice article in this [link](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms), with a main idea to create dynamic component and pass config to it:

```
<form
  class="dynamic-form"
  [formGroup]="form"
  (ngSubmit)="submitted.emit(form.value)">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let field of config;"
    dynamicField
    [config]="field"
    [group]="form">
  </ng-container>
</form>
```